# c# Dataframe - how to visualize dataframe in a not notebook app

Tags: c#, dataframe, ml.net, polyglot

how to visualize a dataframe in a NOT NOTEBOOK APP (in a console application e.g.)

using a library like `XPlot.Plotly` in a console application

```
var data = Enumerable.Range(0, 100).Select(v => v + .0);
Chart.Bar(data).Show();
```

it opens the browser automatically and shows me a chart.

But, how if i want to visualize the entire dataframe in tabular format?

i've tried to configure a `Formatter` but how to visualize?

```
Formatter.Register<DataFrame>((df, writer) =>
{
    var headers = new List<IHtmlContent>();
    headers.Add(th(i("index")));
    headers.AddRange(df.Columns.Select(c => (IHtmlContent)th(c.Name)));
    var rows = new List<List<IHtmlContent>>();
    var take = 20;
    for (var i = 0; i < Math.Min(take, df.Rows.Count); i++)
    {
        var cells = new List<IHtmlContent>();
        cells.Add(td(i));
        foreach (var obj in df.Rows[i])
        {
            cells.Add(td(obj));
        }
        rows.Add(cells);
    }

    var t = table(
        thead(
            headers),
        tbody(
            rows.Select(
                r => tr(r))));

    writer.Write(t);
}, "text/html");
```

It seems to work in a notebook only, how can "to pass" this formatter to `XPlot` (or another library) in order to open the browser and show it ( like  `Chart.Bar(data).Show();` does?

Comment: Have you tried creating a [Google Table chart](https://fslab.org/XPlot//chart/google-table-chart.html)? The code you posted creates HTML anyway. You don't need XPlot for that at all. `Show()` doesn't do any magic either, it [saves the generated HTML to a temp file and opens it with a browser](https://github.com/fslaborg/XPlot/blob/main/src/XPlot.Plotly/Main.fs#L41)

Comment: Is it possible customize the layout of google table chart in order color cells conditionally? (e.g. heatmap)

Comment: end eventually my code `Formatter.Register<DataFrame>` where does it put the html?
if i woluld get this html content i'd try to do the same the method `show()` does

Comment: Nowhere. You're creating a new type of plot, not formatting an existing one. Did you try the Table chart yet? As for `the same the method show does` I already linked to the *actual line* that calls `Process.Start(that.html)`. The *Plot*, in this case Table or Bar generates the HTML and *Show* saves it to disk and opens it

Comment: i can't (i'm not able) to use `XPlot.GoogleCharts.Chart.Table` because this object has a **sign** that i can't translate from f# to c#.
`XPlot.GoogleCharts.Chart.Table<i,j>(IEnumerable<Tuple<i,j>> data, .....` whereas i'm trying to pass the entire dataframe to the table method `XPlot.GoogleCharts.Chart.Table(df)` obviously isn't correct, so should i extract this `IEnumerable<tuple>` from the dataframe and pass it to the method? i didn't found any example of this in c#, incredible